# $scope.myArray not shown after I switch between pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a two page web-app written in AngularJS, which should get the new data from the database every time the page is displayed.

After I load the page freshly, it works perfectly fine. The data is displayed correctly on page A. When I switch to page B, which is not initially visible, it also works. But when I switch back to page A, nothing of the data is displayed. I debugged the array which should be emptied and refilled every time and I saw, that the old data is still there and the new data (which is the same as the old) was added onto this array.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**Views:**

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in mydata">
      <td>
         <a href="{{data.link}}">{{data.linkname}}</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Controllers:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.mydata = [];
    //send request for data to the database...
    //listener for the incoming data is the following function:
    var listener = function(message){
        $scope.mydata.push(message); //message has the expected format
        $scope.$apply();             //just for sure
    };
}]);
```

Comment: When you navigate away, are you doing a full refresh (301) or just a route change?

Comment: When I switch between pages, I do a route change using `$routeProvider`.

Comment: Can you post your complete code? requesting the data from the database is an important piece that was left out, although I don't see how the listener function is called either